# Two battery control

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-operated, charging, low-voltage

I have two Li-ion batteries in my system. (7.4 V 12000 mAh and 7.4 V 2200 mAh; also they have BMS). The larger one of the batteries can be easily removed and installed from my system, so I can charge this battery outside. But other one can't be removed so I need to charge 7.4 V 2200 mAh battery from 7.4 V 12000 mAh in a controlled way.  When switch 1 is closed, switch 2 will be open, so the small battery will begin to charge. I used a boost converter to constantly charge the battery with 8.2 volts, but it got too hot, what can I use instead of the boost circuit?

[image]

Comment: Use a charger. Don't mishandle batteries like that, as mishandled batteries can get damaged and damaged batteries can be unstable and they might explode or burst into flames, leading to injuries or fires.

Comment: what kind of charger ? do you have any recommend a charger circuit ?

Comment: Any charger that is intended for charging lithium batteries. Recommending what to buy would be off topic.

Comment: None of this design is acceptable.  Battery regulation must be separate to avoid long durations of > 10 min with Vbat > 3.8V (x2) in CV mode

Comment: what is your recommend ?

Comment: _”but it got too hot”_ Fix that!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of BMS do you have? **BMS's usually have overcharge and overcurrent protection**, **if your BMS has them you got nothing to worry about** because 18650 can and will heat up a little when charged at high rate, **if you don't want them to heat up that much limit the current**, you should check the balance every few months if your BMS doesn't have a balancing feature.

Comment: The batteries have BMS with over-current and over-voltage protection features. I was just worried that the boost converter was getting too hot. That's why I wanted to verify if my application was correct. Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: @mco you welcome, its nothing to worry about, just make sure not to push the boost converter too far and it has some air around to cool down.